# How to extract only brain part in center in MRI image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I have a MRI image of brain. I need to remove cranium (skull) from MRI and then crop background region which is around brain. How could I do that in python with image processing ?. I have tried using openCV

This is the code which I tried:

```
def crop_brain_contour(image, plot=False):
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)
marker_area = [np.sum(markers==m) for m in range(np.max(markers)) if m!=0] 
largest_component = np.argmax(marker_area)+1                       
brain_mask = markers==largest_component
brain_out = image.copy()
brain_out[brain_mask==False] = (0,0,0)

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
# extreme points
extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

new_image = image[extTop[1]:extBot[1], extLeft[0]:extRight[0]]            

return new_image
```

**These images are similar that i required:**

[image]  [image]

**When i run this code i get this image**
[image]

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
We fix broken code.  We do not write non-trivial models on request.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: @Prune i have made the changes and i cleared it out where the problem is coming!!  i would be such a great help , if you could guide me.

Comment: How about providing a high resolution image to process!

Comment: @fmw42 i need to crop that black region to reduce noise of images. and it will ultimately will give me high accuracy

Comment: Your image is only 170x256 pixels in dimension. That is hardly anything to work on. Do you have a larger version of the image at better resolution? That is a full size image. You  may have posted only a small version.

Comment: Again, please trace and comment on the intermediate results.  Simply handing us wrong output for a complex problem is (generally) not sufficient.  Is the problem in identifying appropriate contours, in the combining of those contours, in the choice of which region was the most important, ... ?

Comment: @fmw42 i have .nii format of that image . Then i use ITK-snap software to get axial view of the brain in .png format. So i can only get 170x256 pixels dimension.

Comment: @Prune yes i am trying to find those contours for center part of image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Convert to grayscale
 - Threshold
 - Apply morphology close
 - Get the largest contour
 - Draw the largest contour as white filled on a black background as a mask
 - OPTIONALLY: erode the mask
 - Get the dimensions of the contour (after optional eroding)
 - Crop the input image and mask to those dimensions
 - Put the mask into the alpha channel of the image to make the outside transparent
 - Save the results
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('mri.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, -1)

# get bounds of contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# crop image and mask
img_crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
mask_crop = mask[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# put mask in alpha channel of image
result = cv2.cvtColor(img_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = mask_crop

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('mri_thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('mri_cropped.png', img_crop)
cv2.imwrite('mri_cropped_alpha.png', result)

# ALTERNATE ERODE mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
thresh2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# get external contour
contours2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours2 = contours2[0] if len(contours2) == 2 else contours2[1]
big_contour2 = max(contours2, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw white filled contour on black background as mask
mask2 = np.zeros_like(thresh2, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask2, [big_contour2], 0, 255, -1)

# get bounds of contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour2)

# crop image and mask
img_crop2 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
mask_crop2 = mask2[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# put mask in alpha channel of image
result2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_crop2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result2[:,:,3] = mask_crop2

# save results
cv2.imwrite("mri_thresh.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("mri_cropped.png", img_crop)
cv2.imwrite("mri_cropped_alpha.png", result)
cv2.imwrite("mri_thresh2.png", thresh2)
cv2.imwrite("mri_cropped2.png", img_crop2)
cv2.imwrite("mri_cropped_alpha2.png", result2)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("mask2", mask2)
cv2.imshow("result2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input:

[image]

Threshold image:

[image]

Mask image:

[image]

Simple crop of image:

[image]

Cropped image with alpha channel:

[image]

Cropped image with alpha channel with optional erode:

[image]